# Node: Exports field in package.json is not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have two repos:

1. my-ui-lib: a UI library imported as a dependency in package.json
2. my-app: a React app that imports components from my-ui-lib

I've bundled my UI library and am trying to update the package.json so that I can import the components like this:

```
import Button from "my-ui-lib/components/Button";
```

instead of

```
import Button from "my-ui-lib/build/components/Button";
```

In my `my-ui-lib`'s package.json I have added this:

```json
  "exports": {
    "./components/": "./build/components/",
    "./constants/": "./build/constants/",
    "./helpers/": "./build/helpers/",
    "./hooks/": "./build/hooks/",
    "./icons/": "./build/icons/"
  },
```

I have also confirmed that the build folder is nested as expected when I open up node_modules inside of my-app:

```
  ▾ my-ui-lib/
    ▾ build/
      ▸ components/
      ▸ constants/
      ▸ helpers/
      ▸ hooks/
      ▸ icons/
```

However, I tried importing my button from just the root but it complains:

```
./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'my-ui-lib/components/Button' in '/Users/edmund/Documents/src/my-app/src'
```

Only when I change it to `import Button from "@twicapp/ui/build/components/Button";` does my page load properly.

I've tried updating the package.json file manually by:

1. opening up `my-app/node_modules/my-ui-lib/package.json`
2. changing up the exports field to remove slashes, periods, etc.
3. refreshing my my-app server

But nothing seems to work. Am I missing something?

Here's my `my-ui-lib` package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "my-ui-lib",
  "version": "0.12.41-beta.43",
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x"
  },
  "exports": {
    "./components/": "./build/components/",
    "./constants/": "./build/constants/",
    "./helpers/": "./build/helpers/",
    "./hooks/": "./build/hooks/",
    "./icons/": "./build/icons/"
  },
  "files": [
    "build"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/icons": "4.3.0",
    "@emotion/react": "11.4.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "11.3.0",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "4.4.2",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "4.4.2",
    "@fullcalendar/react": "4.4.2",
    "@material-ui/core": "4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "4.0.0-alpha.60",
    "@mui/lab": "5.0.0-alpha.45",
    "@mui/material": "5.0.0-rc.0",
    "@tippyjs/react": "4.2.5",
    "antd": "3.26.20",
    "clone": "2.1.2",
    "cloudinary-core": "2.11.4",
    "currency-symbol-map": "5.0.1",
    "date-fns": "2.23.0",
    "dompurify": "2.3.3",
    "final-form": "4.20.2",
    "history": "5.0.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.21",
    "notistack": "1.0.10",
    "polished": "3.7.2",
    "prop-types": "15.7.2",
    "react-final-form": "6.5.3",
    "react-helmet": "6.1.0",
    "react-hook-form": "7.15.1",
    "react-progressbar": "15.4.1",
    "react-text-mask": "5.4.3",
    "recharts": "2.0.0-beta.8",
    "styled-theme": "0.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "7.15.7",
    "@babel/core": "7.15.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "7.15.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-do-expressions": "7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind": "7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent": "7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-logical-assignment-operators": "7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator": "7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator": "7.15.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions": "7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.15.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.14.5",
    "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^5.3.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^21.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-image": "^2.1.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-json": "^4.1.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^13.0.5",
    "@rollup/plugin-url": "^6.1.0",
    "@storybook/addon-a11y": "6.3.12",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "6.3.12",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "6.3.12",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "6.3.1",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "6.3.12",
    "@storybook/addon-postcss": "^2.0.0",
    "@storybook/addon-viewport": "6.3.12",
    "@storybook/addons": "6.3.12",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "3.2.0",
    "@storybook/react": "6.3.12",
    "@storybook/storybook-deployer": "2.8.10",
    "@svgr/rollup": "^5.5.0",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^5.5.0",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "27.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "8.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "1.13.2",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^7.0.3",
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.25.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "24.4.2",
    "eslint-plugin-json": "3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.26.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.4.0",
    "husky": "7.0.2",
    "jest": "27.2.1",
    "lint-staged": "11.1.2",
    "prettier": "2.4.1",
    "prettier-eslint-cli": "5.0.1",
    "pretty-quick": "3.1.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-router": "5.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "5.3.0",
    "rollup": "^2.58.0",
    "rollup-plugin-auto-external": "^2.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-copy": "^3.4.0",
    "rollup-plugin-multi-input": "^1.3.1",
    "rollup-plugin-styles": "^3.14.1",
    "styled-components": "5.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.58.2"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "start-storybook -p 9009",
    "test": "jest",
    "build": "rollup --config",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -o ./docs -s ./.storybook/static",
    "deploy-storybook": "storybook-to-ghpages --out=docs",
    "eslint": "eslint --ignore-path .gitignore ./",
    "eslint:fix": "eslint --fix --ignore-path .gitignore ./",
    "prettier": "prettier -c ./",
    "prettier:fix": "prettier --write ./"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.js": "eslint --cache --fix"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution for your problem? I'm having the exact same issue. Exports are defined correct but neither vscode nor webpack can't resolve the file.

Comment: @Tequilalime I had to change up the way I create the build + only publish the dist/ folder. So ithe node module looks like `my-library/components/Button/index.js`

Comment: @Tequilalime I uploaded a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

You'd better check your `my-app` project, make sure which build tools you use(webpack or rollup or something else?)

Build tools often offer your some fields to configure the moduleResolution strategy in their configuration file, such as `webpack.config.json`.

By the way, `exports` field of package.json will work well when you take node module resolution to import module.

For example:
set up a project like this:

```
tool
  /-- dist
       /-- add.js
  /-- types
       /-- index.d.ts
  package.json
```

add.js:

```js
module.exports.add = function(a, b) { return a + b }
```

index.d.ts:

````js
/**
 * add two number
 *
 * @example
 * ```typescript
 * const c = add(1, 2)
 * 
 * // result: c === 3
 * ```
 */
export declare function add(a: number, b: number): number;
````

package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "tool",
  "exports": {
      ".": {
         "require": "./dist",
      },
      "./*": {
         "require":"./dist/*.js",
         "types": "./types/index.d.ts"
      }
   }
}
```

in tool directory, run `yarn link`;

then, setup another project to import tool package, this project will be like:

```
practice
   main.js
   package.json
```

main.js:

```js
const { add } = require("tool/add")

add(1, 3)
```

package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "practice"
}
```

then, in practice directory, run `yarn link tool`, you will see the changes:

```
practice
   /-- node_modules
           /-- tool
   package.json
   main.js
```

When you open the practice project and look at `main.js` in `vscode`, you will find that there're no type hints about `add`! But we have configured the types in `exports` field of package.json!

To your surprise , we could run `main.js` by `node main.js`, no errors no warns!

This is because when node executes the file, it will look at `exports` field and follow its content, but vscode type hints system don't know this and never give you a hint!

how to solve it?
Just add a jsconfig.json file under practice directory:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
       "moduleResolution": "Node16"
  }
}
```

Do you get it? Yes, we adopt this format to tell vscode the moduleResolution strategy, then you could see the type hints when you hover on the `add`.

So, when you build your app, the build tools maybe offer you configuration field to resolve the module path. Search it!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get exports to work. This is how I worked around it. I had to change the build + publish only the dist folder

[image]